# Creating 95% confidence band with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm having trouble plotting a 95% confidence band with ggplot.

Here is my code:

```
> my.data
               scar response.rate
1               HTS          0.88
2               HTS          0.56
3               HTS          0.56
4               HTS          0.82
5               HTS          0.10
6               HTS          0.47
7               HTS          0.83
8               HTS          0.60
9            Linear          0.83
10           Linear          0.56
11           Linear          0.79
12           Linear          0.55
13           Linear          0.70
14           Linear          0.50
15           Keloid          1.00
16           Keloid          0.83
17           Keloid          1.00
18 Striae Distensae          0.33
19 Striae Distensae          0.33

ggplot(my.data, aes(scar, response.rate))+geom_point()+geom_smooth()
```

The output it produces:

[image]

When I use numbers for the scars, I am able to produce the following:

[image]

Any way I can produce the same graph with the scar type instead of numbers?

Comment: If the scar values are categorical, then a continuous confidence band is probably not appropriate and you should make 4 individual error bars instead. If the scar values are actually numeric, or at least ordered, then you would plot using numeric values as you did and then simply adjust the tick labels after the fact.

Comment: Just a regular `geom_errorbar` would be appropriate for the discrete data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This method you create the CI's manually, then plot them using `geom_errorbar()`

```
library(ggplot2)
# Creating some data:
my.data = data.frame(c(rep("H",5),rep("L",5),rep("K",5),rep("S",5)), rnorm(20,1,.5) )
names(my.data) = c("scar", "response.rate")

# Standard error function
foo = function(x){sd(x)/sqrt(length(x))}

# Creating CI's manually
my.aggs = cbind(aggregate(response.rate ~ scar, data = my.data, FUN = foo),
                aggregate(response.rate ~ scar, data = my.data, FUN = mean))
names(my.aggs) = c("scar","se","","means")

# Plotting
ggplot()+
   geom_point(data = my.data, aes(as.factor(scar), response.rate)) +
   geom_errorbar(data = my.aggs, aes(scar, ymin=means-1.96*se, ymax=means+1.96*se), width=.1) 

# Alternative method that doesn't include points
library(gplots)
plotmeans(response.rate ~ scar, data = my.data)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the info. Unfortunately the plot looks nothing like the first plot I posted.

Comment: I edited to add the photo that the `ggplot` code creates. The data is different from yours since it was randomly generated but they look rather similar to me. Perhaps you were comparing the alternate method I presented? Let me know what changes you would like to be made.